# Clearness Scoring Function

Tags: dataset, algorithms, scoring-rules

Hello to the community,

I would love to hear your opinion about a Prediction Model I am currently working on for my thesis, in order to predict the Clearness of a website.

I created a dataset of 5.000 landing page images.

Then I made a web application where users would vote random pairs of images and choose the image that looked more "clear".

As a result, after getting results from more than 1.000 users Ι have a dataset with the following scheme

```
    "image1"      "image521"   1    
    "image3"      "image241"   0  
    "image35"      "image12"   1  
    :
    :
    :
    "image5"      "image902"   1
```

where I have tuples of the images that have been displayed and if the third value is 0, then the first image is chosen, if the value is 1 the second image was chosen.

Now, my question comes to how I should structure the (Clearness) Score function.

So far the Clearness Score function is calculated with the following way:

```
Clearness =  TimesAnImageIsVoted*100/TimesAnImageIsDisplayed
```

As an example, if an image has been displayed 20 times in 20 unique pairs and has been selected 15 times as the more clear image, then the Clearness would be equal to 75.

Should I take into consideration the pairs, penalize images that are not selected or in general have a more elegant approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem - can you expand a little on what you would like to do with this score? That might help folks understand how it should be constructed.

Comment: @LouisCialdella The scope of creating a Clearness Score is to get an objective value of how "clear" a design is, based on the preference of real humans.
After I am completely sure that I have found the right Clearness values, I will start to train some predictive models in order to get as an input an image and then predict the Clearness score!
I would love to explain more if you want.

Comment: How would you know if you had found the right score? That seems like a key question to answer.

You may find that this is an interesting starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank